# React - Update Global Variable from a Class Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi Stack Overflow Community,

I have the following object

```
const initialState = { count: 0, isOpen: false };
```

in which I want multiple class components i.e.

```
class Class1 extends React.Component <Props, State> {}
class Class2 extends React.Component <Props, State> {}
class Class3 extends React.Component <Props, State> {}
```

to be able to read or update any of the `initialState` values. Does anyone know a way to do this?

I've tried using [state-pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/state-pool) (as shown below) and [react-hooks-global-state](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hooks-global-state) but they only work with a function component. This is the error message when using the first library in a class component:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of
> the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

```
import * as React from "react";
import StatePool from 'state-pool';

const initialState = StatePool.createState({count: 0, isOpen: false});

interface Props {};

interface State {
    isPlayButton: boolean,
};

export class Class1 extends React.Component <Props, State>  {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isPlayButton: true
        };

    const [state, setState] = StatePool.useState(initialState);
        
    };

    ...
}
```

Comment: Personally, I would use [Context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context)

Comment: Indeed either pass this as Context or props, but also consider not using class-based components. They should probably no longer be used for any new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Phil mentioned, the React context allows data sharing in a component tree. You can share the `state` and an `update()` method by context.

On the consumer side(`<Class1/>`, `<Class2/>`, `<Class3/>`), they can get the `state` and `update()` methods from the context.

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';

type State = { count: number; isOpen: boolean };

const SharedContext = React.createContext<{
  state: State;
  update(state: Partial<State>): void;
}>({
  state: undefined,
  update(state: Partial<State>) {},
});

class SharedContextProvider extends React.Component<
  React.PropsWithChildren,
  State
> {
  state: State = { count: 0, isOpen: false };
  render() {
    return (
      <SharedContext.Provider
        value={{
          state: this.state,
          update: (newState: State) => this.setState(newState),
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </SharedContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

class Class1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SharedContext.Consumer>
        {(context) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <div>count in class 1:{context.state.count}</div>
              <button
                onClick={() =>
                  context.update({ count: context.state.count + 1 })
                }
              >
                increase in class 1
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </SharedContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
class Class2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SharedContext.Consumer>
        {(context) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <div>count in class 2:{context.state.count}</div>
              <button
                onClick={() =>
                  context.update({ count: context.state.count + 1 })
                }
              >
                increase in class 2
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </SharedContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
class Class3 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SharedContext.Consumer>
        {(context) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <div>count in class 3:{context.state.count}</div>
              <button
                onClick={() =>
                  context.update({ count: context.state.count + 1 })
                }
              >
                increase in class 3
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </SharedContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <SharedContextProvider>
      <Class1 />
      <Class2 />
      <Class3 />
    </SharedContextProvider>
  );
};
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-8kbj1r?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

Comment: Hi Lin Du, I wasn't aware of React Context, and this solves my problem. Really thanks for this. Would this still work if each class component was called with the SharedContextProvider individually? For example, 'const App1 = () => {return (<Provider>Class1</Provider>)}' and 'const App2 = () => {return (<Provider>Class2</Provider>)} '.

Comment: @Fxs7576 No, it doesn't. If you create multiple component instances of  `<Provider/>`, each of them will have its local state. They are not shared.